# Is it acceptable to format a CV for someone else?

Tags: resume, helping

Assume that someone (friend, family) asks you to format his/her CV. They typically might want to apply to a job where text processing etc. is not one of the key requirements and they ask you to do it in order to have a nice result and/or to win time, although they could probably do it themselves in Word.

Can it be negative for them? Imagine for instance that the interviewer asks them how they made such a nice CV.

Comment: Some recruitment agencies will reformat your CV for you if they don't like it. How can you doing it for a friend be a problem.

Comment: @Snowlockk good point, happens all the time in the US.

Comment: Why would it be "negative for them"? I've helped friends with their resumes on many instances over the years. Heck, there's services out there that offer that exact service. The important thing is that it's accurate.

Comment: When you're good with Microsoft Word, everyone wants your help formatting resumes. :'(

Comment: @corsiKa Or when you're good with LaTeX... :)

Comment: The problems with making someone (especially someone technophobic) a really nicely formatted CV is that often they're largely incapable of making amendments to it. Better to show them [how to make a nice CV themselves](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/28/fish/)

Comment: The other issue is that often I see candidates whose CV (and the language used therein) is clearly well beyond their levels of IT skill and literacy skill. At that point it becomes worthless interviewing them. I don't want the person sat in front of me, I want the person who wrote their CV :-)

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't list "Single-handedly drafted this CV" as one of your accomplishments.

Comment: "Imagine for instance that the interviewer asks them how they made such a nice cv." Then they tell that their friend made it for them. Unless the company is hiring a resume writer, I don't see why this is a problem.

Comment: @MaskedMan - Because a CV that doesn't reflect the candidate is misleading?

Comment: @Richard but a CV is not a portfolio.  It is about the candidate but need not even be the work of the candidate. I worked for a consulting firm for a while that actually had a person who was a CV writer who would take the facts you provided and create a CV in the corporate voice and style.

Comment: @Ukko - I speak from experience when I say that it can be hugely disappointing when a candidate with an excellent CV turns out to be a stumble-brained nincompoop who merely happens to have a *friend* with LaTeX experience and a charming turn of phrase.

Comment: @Richard Why do you care about the format of the CV more than its content?

Comment: @MaskedMan - Well, for example when you're dealing with low- and entry-level roles, it can be very informative to see whether the candidate can read, write and use IT. Professional CV-writing disguises that entirely.

Comment: Then make it clear in the requirement that candidates should write their own resume. What's next? Candidate did not polish his shoes by himself or did not iron his clothes by himself, hence interviewer was disappointed?

Comment: @Richard Isn't that what the interview process is for?  Regardless of the rules you set in place, you can't possibly verify that a candidate wrote their own CV.  If you're weeding out candidates purely on CV appearance you deserve to get burned occasionally by people who didn't write their CV.

Comment: @JMac - Many companies seem to be switching back to an on-site application form precisely for that reason, to weed out those that had someone else wholly write their CVs for them. I don't have an axe to grind with those who've had their CVs *polished* but when it's rewritten from scratch, that's when you end up with a CV that doesn't reflect the candidate.

Comment: @Richard But that's a problem with the selection process, not the candidates themselves (you even mention there is another process that fixes this).  The fact is, if people can pay money to increase their chances of getting an interview, it seems only reasonable that some will.

Comment: @JMac - For me the issue is one of *ownership*. If you're merely the recipient of a CV that you **can't confidently amend**, that contains **floral descriptions of jobs that you'd never use** and **language that utterly defies your levels of literacy and spoken English**, then that's a bad thing

Comment: @Richard I never said it was a good thing.  I'm saying that by using CV's as a screening process you are inherently vulnerable to that. You can't use it as a gospel representation of what to expect from the employee.  It may be disappointing when someone is nothing like their CV suggests; but there's a reason job screening is a multiple tier process.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Yes it's fine

It's fairly normal to ask someone to proof-read your resume or to help with layout, so there's nothing wrong there.

There's so many resumes sent out with elementary mistakes, so another set of eyes really helps in getting things right.

If the recruitment is happening via an agency, the hiring company won't see your resume, they'll just see a copy/paste of the relevant parts (recruiters won't want the client seeing your contact details).

In general, it's far more important to get the facts right than for it to look pretty.

Comment: I think the only possible exception would be if you're applying to be a graphics designer and you have someone else design a fancy CV for you because you can't since that would be misrepresenting your skillset.

Comment: True, but this isn't the case for the question above.  Still, if you're being recruited via an agency, then the CV will be mangled via a chop/paste.  For this kind of job, you'd probably submit part of a portfolio as part of your resume.

Comment: You're right of course, I just get a disproportionate amount of satisfaction out of being a pedant.

Comment: In my experience if the formatting of the cv\resume is poor, the person reading the document will never get to the substance ( facts ).

Comment: @MisterSortOfPositive Ok.  The point I'm trying to make is that a CV with obvious spell/grammatical problems comes across as being worse than something with some formatting problems (recruiters typically destroy formatting anyway).

Comment: But I agree that using Comic Sans is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: When the recruitment is happening via an agency, they might even reformat your resume all together to be able to provide all their candidates in the same format to their client(s).

Comment: I am sorry, but can't a CV be without obvious spelling/grammar problems AND also look good? I would bet HR reacts to this the same way as humans do often: It looks good, so it must be good. And if it is handled by an agency and they reformat there is nothing you can do, but still it does not hurt. And also you should always send out PDFs (as sending out doc or odf will mess up the formatting) anyways, so how they copy&paste this at the agency is not really your concern.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it acceptable to format a cv for someone else?

Yes, of course. I help friends write and format their resumes all the time.

Nobody knows or cares who wrote or formatted your CV/resume. They only care that it accurately reflects you, your background, and your career.

I can't imagine that an interviewer would ask about a nice resume. But if they did, saying "Well, I had a friend who is really good at it give me a hand." is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Exactly, when asked, just be honest about it. It shows you can network, know your weak and strong points & people are willing to help you. For a CV, that is - not for a portfolio...

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, its fine to help someone with their resume/cv.

I have been complimented on my resume for its format and such in the past, but never has an interviewer asked **how** I came up with it.  It is very low risk in my opinion to whomever your helping.

In fact, there are several companies who make a living by creating resumes for professionals at all levels.  Their resume is the first step, the golden ticket if you will, to earn the interview.

I would do whatever I felt necessary to make mine as solid as possible.  **Formatting and content both matter**.  Think of it as their first impression with the potential employer.  Do what you can to make is as good as it can be.

Answer (score 3):

Just to go against the grain...

It can possibly be a problem, IF.

1. You use words or phraseology that the person doesn't normally use
2. You embellish
3. The person cannot recite it from memory.  If he doesn't know what's on his own resume, that's a BIG red flag
4. It doesn't "fit" the job applied for.  You want your resume to be fine tuned to hit the requirements of the job for which you are applying.

To avoid this, make sure you go over the CV as you are making the changes, and the person understands them and can go over it with you line by line and memorize it.

**Edited to add:**

To expand on my point #1.  If I am interviewing someone and the language at the interview doesn't match what I've seen on the resume, it's going to make me think that something is wrong, that I'm not interviewing the same person I saw on the resume.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely acceptable to proofread someone's CV/resume.

However, if you are really asking about "crafting" a resume, that's a different matter. By "crafted" resume I mean a type of resume, which, while not making any obviously false claims, presents the facts in a misleading manner. For example, a resume may suggest that the candidate is a rocket scientist, while actually he worked at Goddard Space Flight Center as a janitor.

So, what can go bad is that the reviewer (or should we call him co-author?) might have his best intentions and embellish the candidate's profile, but the hiring manager would not be impressed. The remedy is simple - stick to the facts, and ask yourself, if you were the hiring manager yourself, would you like this candidate?

Answer (score 1):

**Limited answer - this is not fine if...**

If the C.V. or job description describes the person as being good at design, formatting documents, or experienced with LaTeX, then the person should format it themselves.

In this (very limited) case, the implicit assumption the company will come away with is that you are presenting your C.V. as an example of your work. Having someone else format it for you is likely to lead them to a false conclusion.

If not in this situation, see any of the other answers.